# How to hide a column in @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable

Tags: angular

I am implementing @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable package in Angular-12. I have these columns:

component:

```
this.columns = [
  {
    key: 'id',
    title: '<div class="blue"> ID</div>',
    width: 60,
    sorting: true,
    align: {
      head: 'center',
      body: 'center'
    },
    vAlign: {
      head: 'bottom',
      body: 'middle'
    },
    cellTemplate: this.idTpl
  },
  {
    key: 'first_name',
    title: '<div class="blue">First Name</div>',
    width: 100
  },
  {
    key: 'last_name',
    title: '<div class="blue">Last Name</div>',
    width: 100
  },
  {
    key: 'active',
    title: '<div class="blue">Active</div>',
    align: {
      head: 'left'
    },
    width: 100,
    sorting: true,
  },
  {
    key: '',
    title: '<div class="blue">Action</div>',
    align: {
      head: 'center',
      body: 'center'
    },
    sorting: false,
    width: 80,
    cellTemplate: this.actionTpl
  }
];
```

HTML:

```
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="userInfoList" [columns]="columns"
  [options]="options">
  <ngx-caption>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
        <b>
                  <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Site Info. List
              </b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngx-caption>

  <ng-template #addressTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #actionTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>

</ngx-datatable>
```

I want to hide key: 'id' from being displayed at the HTML (I only need the row for routing in edit and delete).

I used visible: false but it's not working.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want the id column, how about removing the `{ key: 'id',... }` from `this.columns`?

Comment: @YongShun -  I don't want to remove the the { key: 'id',... } because I want to use as refence row in edit (click)="editEmployee(row) and delete